"Failed to add user: The API access for bot users is restricted. The method you tried to invoke cannot be executed as a bot(InviteToChannelRequest)"
I've a list of user ID's and I'm trying to add them to my telegram channel, I'm using my user credentials, yet I still get the "cannot be executed as a bot" error.
This is my code:
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import InviteToChannelRequest

api_id = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
api_hash = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
phone_number = '+xxxxxxxxxxx'

# Connect to Telegram
with TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    # Login using your phone number
    client.connect()
    if not client.is_user_authorized():
        client.send_code_request(phone_number)
        client.sign_in(phone_number, input('Enter the code: '))

    # Load user IDs from the file
    with open("user_ids.txt", "r") as file:
        user_ids = [int(line.strip()) for line in file.readlines()]

    # Get the "xxxxxxxx" channel
    channel = client.get_entity('xxxxxxxxxx')

    # Add users to the channel
    for user_id in user_ids:
        try:
            client(InviteToChannelRequest(channel, [user_id]))
            print(f"User with ID {user_id} added to the channel.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to add user with ID {user_id}: {e}")

What am I doing wrong?
